# how to default trigger click an dynamic anchor tag in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This is the code of my render function:

```
render: function(){
  var c = $.map(this.state.x, function(){
    return(
      <a href="#" onClick={this.function()}>{x}</a>`
    )
  })

 return(
   <div>{c}</div>
 )
}
```

I am here returning dynamically anchor tags from variable.

How can I trigger click my first anchor tag by default ?

(I want my anchor to be clicked after mount)

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `componentDidMount` and call `this.function()`.

Comment: I have done that but not able to access my anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function in `componentDidMount` along with the index of the link clicked will do the trick for you.

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  
  getInitialState(){
    return {
      x: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleClick(0);
  },
  handleClick(idx) {
    console.log('Clicked' + this.state.x[idx]);
  },
  render: function(){
    var self = this;
    var c = this.state.x.map(function(x, index){
      return(
        <div>
        <a href="#" onClick={self.handleClick.bind(this,index)}>{x}</a></div>
      );
    })

   return(
     <div>{c}</div>
   )
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: @Shruti did you try my solution. Let me know you feedback if its working or not